# how to pass or inject standard .net object in windows runtime class

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, windows-runtime

I have a WinRT project which is having one WinRT class. Now, I want to inject or pass on a .net standard object into the constructor or methods of WinRT class. But somehow, It is not allowing. Though If I use static methods of standard .net class, then i can access and call static methods.

So, just want to know is there way to pass in user defined interface or types in WinRT Classes.

I have been through this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/creating-windows-runtime-components-in-csharp-and-visual-basic#declaring-types-in-windows-runtime-components)

But could not find anything

Comment: Can you provide more information, maybe even some code you're trying to get working (and the error it gives you)? In general, .NET objects are not understood by WinRT.

Answer (score 0):

> how to pass or inject standard .net object in windows runtime class

You could make [.Net Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) class library and package .Net Standard object and then reference it within Windows Runtime components. Then call runtime method in uwp project.

[image]

**Code segment**

```
public sealed class RunTimeCore
{
    public static string GetString()
    {
        return TestLib.TestTool.GetString();
    }
}


public class TestTool
{
    public static string GetString() {

        return "hello";
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var str = RuntimeComponent.RunTimeCore.GetString();
```